# How to query Apache's access_log with lnav

Tags: logging, mac-osx

I'm trying to use [lnav](http://lnav.org/features/) to query Apache's access_log on macOS. It looks really nice, but when querying with SQL, I get no results.

I'm starting the program with `./lnav /private/var/log/apache2/access_log`, which shows the log file. Then I type `v` for the SQL result view, and then `;` to enter the SQL query `SELECT cs_uri_query, sc_status FROM access_log;` and press enter.

In the bottom row lnav says `Now rows matched`. Same goes for the query `SELECT * FROM access_log`.

I'm clearly missing something. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Apple tweaked the access_log file format, and you need to install a custom file format with lnav. The guys from lnav have an active forum, and they provided [an answer over there](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lnav/aWLs2PCTtVU), including the format file.